# Known exact values of the $\operatorname{Li}_3$ function

Tags: special-functions, closed-form, big-list, polylogarithm

We know some exact values of the [*trilogarithm*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Trilogarithm.html) $\operatorname{Li}_3$ function.

Known real analytic values for $\operatorname{Li}_3$:

- $\operatorname{Li}_3(-1)=-\frac{3}{4} \zeta(3)$
- $\operatorname{Li}_3(0)=0$
- $\operatorname{Li}_3\left( \frac{1}{2} \right) = \frac{7}{8} \zeta(3) - \frac{1}{12} \pi^2 \ln 2 + \frac{1}{6} \ln^3 2$
- $\operatorname{Li}_3(1) = \zeta(3),$ where $\zeta(3)$ is the [Apéry's constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AperysConstant.html)
- $\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\phi^{-2}\right)=\frac{4}{5} \zeta(3) + \frac{2}{3} (\ln \phi)^3 - \frac{2}{15} \pi^2 \ln \phi,$ where $\phi$ is the [golden ratio](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoldenRatio.html).

Using [identities](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog/17/ShowAll.html) for the list above we could also get:

- $\operatorname{Li}_3(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{4} \ln 2 + \frac{7}{8} \zeta(3) - \frac{\pi}{2} \ln^2(2) \cdot i,$ or we could write into this [alternate form](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polylog%283%2C2%29).
- $\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\phi^2\right) = \frac{4}{5} \zeta(3) - \frac{2}{3} \ln^3 \phi + \frac{8\pi^2}{15}\ln \phi - 2\pi\ln^2(\phi) \cdot i,$ or there is an [alternate form here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polylog%283%2Cgoldenratio%5E2%29).

We know even less about complex argumented values:

- $\operatorname{Li}_3(i)=-\frac{3}{32}\zeta(3) +\frac{\pi^3}{32} i$
- $\operatorname{Li}_3(-i)=-\frac{3}{32}\zeta(3) -\frac{\pi^3}{32} i.$

There are some partial result for complex cases:

- $\Im\left[ \operatorname{Li}_3 \left( \frac{1 \pm i}{\sqrt{2}} \right) \right] = \pm \frac{7\pi^3}{256}$, and there is an [expression for the real part](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Re%28polylog%283%2C%281%2Bi%29%2Fsqrt%282%29%29%29) in term of derivatives of digamma function,
- other related specific values around the unit circle like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polylog%283%2C%28-1%29%5E%281%2F6%29%29%29) or [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polylog%283%2C%28-1%29%5E%281%2F8%29%29%29), [etc](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polylog%283%2C%28-1%29%5E%281%2F9%29%29%29).

Lucian said the following in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918680/closed-form-for-the-imaginary-part-of-textli-3-big-frac1i2-big):

- $\Re\left[\text{Li}_3\left(\dfrac{1+i}2\right)\right]=\dfrac{\ln^32}{48}-\dfrac5{192}~\pi^2~\ln2+\dfrac{35}{64}~\zeta(3).$

While working on Lucian's problem [I was able to specify this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/932651/153012)

- $\Re \left[\operatorname{Li}_3(1 \pm i)\right] = \frac{\pi^2}{32} \ln 2 + \frac{35}{64} \zeta(3).$

Than I got the idea to write a question, maybe someone could give us some more specific values of the trilogarithm function.

Comment: A somewhat related recent [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/935366/19661).

Comment: You probably know that for all $x>1,\ \Im\big[\operatorname{Li}_3(x)\big]=-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln^2x$.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov could you give me some reference or a proof for this property? If we are here I'm also interested for a proof of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/936195/153012).

Comment: It follows from the [formula 10.08.17.0047.01](http://functions.wolfram.com/10.08.17.0047.01) at _Wolfram Functions_.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Sorry for that, but I don't exactly see how is it comes from the identity what you linked. Could you explain me by giving more details? By the ways using this identity then this more general formula is also true:
$$\Im[\operatorname{Li}_3(z)]=-\frac14 \,\pi \, \left( \ln  \left( {z}^{-1} \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( 
 \left| {\frac {-1+z}{z}} \right| z+z-1 \right)  \left( -1+z \right) ^
{-1},$$
for all $1 \neq z>0$. Between $0<z<1$ it is zero.

Comment: Going higher, the situation seems to be reminiscent of how we know closed forms for $\rm{Li}_2\big(\tfrac12\big)$ and $\rm{Li}_3\big(\tfrac12\big)$, but not for higher.

Answer (score 6):

It appears that
$$
\Im\left[\mathrm{Li}_3\left((-1)^{\frac{1}{2^n}}\right) \right]=\frac{(2^n-1)(2^{n+1}-1)}{3\cdot2^{3n+2}}\pi^3
$$
but that's by experimentation.

Comment: What is the relationship between $k$ and $n$?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The $k$ was supposed to be an $n$.

Comment: For example for $n=1$ the right-hand side equals zero, but the left-hand side is non-zero. Other values seem also incorrect.

Comment: My apologies, two typos in one post. 
Have changed $2^{n-1}$ to $2^{n+1}$, which is what I originally meant.