# On the integral $\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{\text{Li}_3(1-z)}{\sqrt{z(1-z)}}\,dz$

Tags: integration, reference-request, special-functions, hypergeometric-function, polylogarithm

This questions is related to [my previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2798619/about-the-integral-int-0-pi-4-log4-cos-theta-d-theta).

> I am interested in a explicit evaluation in terms of Euler sums for
>   $$ \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\text{Li}_3(\cos^2\theta)\,d\theta = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{\text{Li}_3(1-z)}{\sqrt{z(1-z)}}\,dz.$$

It is not difficult to show that
$$ \int_{0}^{\color{red}{1}}\frac{\text{Li}_3(1-z)}{\sqrt{z(1-z)}}\,dz =-\frac{\pi^3}{3}\log(2)+\frac{4\pi}{3}\log^3(2)+2\pi\zeta(3)\tag{A}$$
but I have not managed to make a wise use of the [trilogarithm functional identities](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Trilogarithm.html) for computing
$$ \int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{\text{Li}_3(z)}{\sqrt{z(1-z)}}\,dz\stackrel{\text{IBP}}{\longrightarrow}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\theta\cot(\theta)\text{Li}_2(\sin^2\theta)\,d\theta \quad\text{or}\quad\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{\text{Li}_3(z)-\text{Li}_3(1-z)}{\sqrt{z(1-z)}}\,dz ,$$
which would have solved the problem. One might need substantial extensions of the result about $\mathcal{I}(a,b)$ proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438381/closed-form-of-int-01-frac-ln2x-sqrtxa-bx-dx/1438525#1438525) by [nospoon](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/219995/nospoon). I am expecting the integral above to be related with Euler sums with (total) weight five. Maybe the shifted-Fourier-Chebyshev expansion of $\text{Li}_3(x)$ over $(0,1)$ is already known in the literature, but I have not been able to find it.

Comment: There is no tag "polylogarithms"? (I cannot understand the classification in (hypergeometric-function)...)

Comment: @dan_fulea: You are right, I forgot to add it. The *hypergeometric* tag is due to the fact that such integral gives a closed form for a peculiar $\phantom{}_5 F_4$ with half-integer parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By brutally evaluating such poly-logsine integrals, or those quadratic Euler sums @user 1591719 proposed, one have

- $\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\text{Li}_3(z)}{\sqrt{z (1-z)}} \, dz=-\frac{\pi ^2 C}{6}+C \log ^2(2)-56 \Im(\text{Li}_4(1+i))+4 \log (2) \Im(\text{Li}_3(1+i))+\pi  \zeta (3)+\pi  \log ^3(2)+\frac{17}{24} \pi ^3 \log (2)+\frac{7 \psi ^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{256}-\frac{7 \psi ^{(3)}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{256}$
- $\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\text{Li}_3(1-z)}{\sqrt{z (1-z)}} \, dz=\frac{\pi ^2 C}{6}-C \log ^2(2)+56 \Im(\text{Li}_4(1+i))-4 \log (2) \Im(\text{Li}_3(1+i))+\pi  \zeta (3)+\frac{1}{3} \pi  \log ^3(2)-\frac{25}{24} \pi ^3 \log (2)-\frac{7 \psi ^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{256}+\frac{7 \psi ^{(3)}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{256}$

See [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.12155) for the methods of calculating quadratic Euler sums. [This](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.03957) offers a far more  systematic and advanced solution.

Comment: Much appreciated! (+1) and accepted.

Answer (score 4):

This is meant to be just *a comment* (too large to add it in the comments section)

$$I=\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{2}{3}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{n(\overbrace{H_n^3+3H_nH_n^{(2)}+2H_n^{(3)})}^{G1}-3 (\overbrace{H_n^2+ H_n^{(2)})}^{G2}}{2n(2n-1)(2n-2)}.$$

A wise next move would be to split the series into 2 series using the groups $G1$ and $G2$ and try to calculate the resulting series like that. In the mathematical literature there are nice, useful representations for those harmonic numbers groups.

Comment: The series related to G2 are manageable. Then we may perform a partial fraction decomposition and exploit the results of Xu, Yang and Zhang (*Explicit evaluation of quadratic Euler sums*) to compute two other pieces. The hardcore part is the evaluation of $$ \sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n \frac{H_n^3+3H_n H_n^{(2)}+2H_n^{(3)}}{2n-1} $$ which does not seem to be covered by classical results.

Comment: On the other hand such sum is related to $\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\log^3(\cos\theta)\,d\theta$ which has been computed by nospoon. Can you provide the derivation of the identity above in full detail? I believe I might be able to turn it into a complete solution. (+1) in the meanwhile.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I checked all the integrals behind the scene. I think all of them can be calculated by combining real and complex methods, but there is some work to do there. Before making any update I want to investigate the possibility of getting major shortcuts.

Comment: Perfectly fine. You are probably already aware of it, but consider that the integrals $\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\log^\mu(\cos t)\,dt$ and $\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\log^\mu(\sin t)\,dt$ for $\mu\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ are known, even if WA does not return them in a nice closed form.